# ILocation interface in ILocationApi.h

Tags: c#, c++, geolocation

I found the ILocation interface in the ILocationApi.h. Is there a possibility to get this interface in C#. I dont want to use the Devices.location namespace. The reason why i'm looking into this interface is so that I can get the position of the device using the location sensors. I have already tried the geocoordinatewatcher. It works but not always. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: geocoordinatewatcher uses ILocation. So the answer to the 'is it usable' question is yes. But why do you think using it directly would yield better results?

Comment: I have seen a lot of complaints on the geocoordinate watcher and I faced the same issue as well. The geocoordinate watcher has an event postionchanged. In order to get the coordinates, I need to wait for that event to fire and many a time it does not fire. I tried using it directly and I get the coordinates immediately. But I got the coordinates immediately in c++ code and now comes the issue between managed and unmanaged code which I have handled but I still feel this can be ported to c#

Answer (score 2):

So this is what I've come up with after doing some research along these lines.

For up to .Net 4.8 you have the [System.Devices.Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location?view=netframework-4.8)

For anything after .Net 4.8 they suggest you move to UWP and use [Windows.Devices.GeoLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation?view=winrt-22621).

If you're not using UWP then you are kind of stuck with the [Location COM Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/locationapi/nn-locationapi-ilocation) library. And I say stuck, as they talk as if it may not be supported in the future and I haven't verified if it's still supported on Windows 11, but I think it is.